# Resource files in a Java program

Tags: java, cmd, runtime

l want to be able to run a bat file compiled in my java app. Everything runs fine from the netbeans IDE but when l build and run, the cmd is not able to run the resource file bundled in the jar file. l run the bat file with cmd(Runtime in java). From the image below, the application package is the apksec, and  others are resource folders with files l want to use in the program, the bat file is in the res folder,
When l run the app directly from cmd

```
C:\Users\slab1>java -jar C:\Users\slab1\Pictures\training\dist\ApkSec.jar
```

l get error

```
'file:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

[image]

The code snippet to run the bat file using cmd below

[image]

How can l get a path to run the bundled resource file in the jar?

Comment: do not insert screenshots but your code here

Comment: `getDexToolPath()` is returning something like `file://c/blahblah`.  I don't think what you're trying will work; how can your OS run a program that is effectively zipped inside a jar?

Comment: what is the output from `<can't copy from image>` (I think) the 5th line

Answer (score 0):

Please take care of parameters you are passing to exec method. Here is an example from - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec_envp.htm

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

     // create a new array of 2 strings
     String[] cmdArray = new String[2];

     // first argument is the program we want to open
     cmdArray[0] = "notepad.exe";

     // second argument is a txt file we want to open with notepad
     cmdArray[1] = "example.txt";

     // print a message
     System.out.println("Executing notepad.exe and opening example.txt");

     // create a process and execute cmdArray and currect environment
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray,null);

     // print another message
     System.out.println("example.txt should now open.");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: he problem is that the getClass().getResource() java functions add file:/// in the directory part. and when l remove the file:/// and ! from the directory path, l get nullpointerexception erroe